# Я кот-таки / Я кот таки

Tags: дефис

Если следовать Розенталю, то, как он написал, *-таки* пишется через дефис только с глаголами, другими частицами и наречиями. А в то же самое время Лопатин в своём справочнике русского языка говорит, что *-таки* через дефис также пишется с причастиями и деепричастиями, а также с любими сказуемыми. Грамота.ру в этом плане думает так же, как Розенталь. Теперь я даже не знаю, по-честному, кому и верить. Можете мне в этом, совы, помочь разобраться?

Если придерживаться Лопатину, то в следующих случаях мы используем дефис (1.), а если остальным двум знайкам - без дефиса таки (2.).

**1)** 1. Я - это кот-таки; 2. Моя машина, мною водясь-таки, упала в канаву и сгнила дотла; 3. Раскачанный-таки на люстре, Том-кот сбежал-убежал; 4. Мой самолёт и пароход быстрые-таки; 5. Он уже наверху-таки.

**2)** 1. Я - это кот таки; 2. Моя машина, мною водясь таки, упала в канаву и сгнила дотла; 3. Раскачанный таки на люстре, Том-кот сбежал-убежал; 4. Мой самолёт и пароход быстрые таки; 5. Он уже наверху таки.

Comment: ДА. вы правы, решения в двух источниках не совпадают Но чтобы выбрать, надо знать хотя бы что-то о частице ТАКИ. Почему она пишется по-разному, какой в этом смысл. Вот о чем надо бы спросить. А иначе как выбирать: мне больше нравится Розенталь, а мне Лопатин?

Comment: Я что-то не могу найти, почему по-разному она пишется. Может, Вы знаете?

Comment: А вы читали тему https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474183/Как-объяснить-правило-Розенталя-о-написании-частицы-таки-дефис-или-раздельно  Там в моем комментарии  говорится о значениях частицы в словаре Евгеньевой. Ну и фонетику дефисного и раздельного письма надо учитывать, но это уже сложнее. Так что непростое решение у вашей задачки. Что касается ПРАВИЛ... Даже если принять точку зрения  Лопатина, то будет: Я кот таки... Здесь именное сказуемое без связки, а  "таки" с именами пишется раздельно. Что касается прич. и дееприч., то написания с дефисом выглядят приемлемо, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Лопатин** (правильный вариант)

1. Я – это ***кот таки***; 2. Моя машина, мною ***водясь-таки***, упала в канаву и сгнила дотла; 3. ***Раскачанный-таки*** на люстре, Том-кот сбежал-убежал; 4. Мой самолёт и пароход ***быстрые таки***; 5. Он уже ***наверху-таки.***

**Именные части** сказуемого (очень решительно!) пишем раздельно, у Лопатина дефисное написание используется для причастий, деепричастий и **предикативных слов** (именно такие примеры приводятся в правиле).

**Розенталь** (правильный вариант)

Я - это кот ***таки***; 2. Моя машина, мною ***водясь(?)таки***, упала в канаву и сгнила дотла; 3. ***Раскачанный(?)таки*** на люстре, Том-кот сбежал-убежал; 4. Мой самолёт и пароход ***быстрые таки***; 5. Он уже н***аверху-таки.***

У Розенталя наречия пишутся через дефис ***(наверху-таки***).

**Вывод**

Розенталь просто **не рассматривает** варианты с причастием и деепричастием, которые используются редко. Но если их применять, то надо писать **по Лопатину**. Через дефис пишутся и другие предикативные формы (***рад-таки***). Такое решение вполне приемлемо и, как вариант, связано с **разным значением**"таки" для глагольных и именных форм (уступительное или усилительное, см. **словарь**).

В остальном варианты **совпадают.**