# Как объяснить правило Розенталя о написании частицы «таки» (дефис или раздельно)?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис, частицы

Правило Розенталя регламентирует выбор формы письма, но **причину не указывает.** Особенно неясен вариант с глаголом: ***ушел-таки и таки запер***. Ведь какая-то **логика** должна быть в таком написании. А если правило непонятно, то о нем забывают и пишут **как кому нравится** (как бы не образуется «генетическая память» по этой теме:))

**Вопрос:** Почему именно такое правило, а не другое? Меня интересует информация из каких-либо источников или ваше мнение.

Спасибо.

[**Розенталь, пункт 4**](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=74)

Частица -***таки*** пишется **через дефис:**

1. после **глаголов**: настоял-таки, ушёл-таки;
2. после **наречий**: верно-таки, довольно-таки, опять-таки, прямо-таки, так-таки;
3. после **частиц:** действительно-таки, неужели-таки.

В остальных случаях (после существительных, местоимений, прилагательных) частица ***-таки*** пишется **отдельно**: *Он таки бросил семью; Большую таки дачу себе построили. Ср.: …Но **таки упёк** своего товарища (Г.); …**Я таки запер** её и в этот раз (Дост.).*

Answer (score 1):

Ну может, после пишется через дефис в основном, а перед словом - это от "всё-таки" сокращение, без всё, ну и ударение можно, если на первый слог - то через дефис я бы писал теперь-такИ, а если на последний слог, то тАки раздельно.

Гоголь Шинель:

*"...существо, переносившее покорно канцелярские насмешки и без всякого чрезвычайного дела сошедшее в могилу, но для которого **всё же таки**, хотя перед самым концом жизни, мелькнул светлый гость в виде шинели, ожививший на миг бедную жизнь, и на которое так же потом нестерпимо обрушилось несчастие, как обрушивалось на царей и повелителей мира..."*

"Всё же" и отдельно "тАки".

Фонвизин:

"*Да ведь не поклонятся ― **чистехонько таки высекут** и плакать не велят.*" - всё-таки высекут.

Новиков (1769г):

"Сперва **я было таки листков** с десяток без троякого прочитания не оставлял, да и во сне про них видал; а ныне ужесть как несносны, да и скучно об них ведать, что они в свете есть." - сперва я было всё-таки листков с десять, значит тАки.

Радищев (хех):

*По сiôсь день господень **всiô таки** у нас, родимой, погода стоит добрая, и мы почти со всем господским хлебом управились: авось таки милосливой спас подержит над нами свою руку, и даст нам еще хорошую погоду, так мы и со своим хлебишком управимся!* - Тут как-то всё мимо тАки.

"Из окружения "демянского мешка ", **немцы-таки вышли**." Михаил Карпов. Список Визенталя (2003) // «Совершенно секретно», 05.05.2003 - не знает правило)

*"Стоило это мне немалых хлопот; впрочем, при содействии одного из царских денщиков, **я-таки** достиг цели и застал царя дома неодетым, в кожаном, как у ремесленника, фартуке, сидящим за токарным станком."*  А. А. Нартов. Рассказы о Петре Великом (1785-1786) - не определился ещё.

А. Т. Болотов. Жизнь и приключения Андрея Болотова, описанные самим им для своих потомков. Письма 91-96 (1800)
*...и все книги его, которых **таки-было** довольно, с великою жадностию пересматривающего...* - оригинально, и он же: - *"**Да как-таки так**, подхватил он.."*

И снова он: - *"**Да! таки стоит копейки**, другой, третей, ― сказал он: ― и сотняга рублей надобна"* - прямо как я пишет, с маленькой буквы продолжает предложение, да еще и с таки, как же смело! мне нравится, пожалуй, буду ставить тире после таки-таки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и примеры! Интересное у вас мнение,  я тоже думала о "всё-таки". Но ударение на частицу при дефисном написании обычно не падает, я произношу "тепЕрь-таки", если надо выделить это наречие в предложении.  А вот в препозиции надо смотреть... Если ТАКИ – это отдельное слово, то у него будут права обычных слов, то есть ударение ставится в предложении, например в его конце перед точкой.

Comment: @Sharon ну ударения нет, с одной стороны, но какой-акцент есть, потому что Ии конечная произносится, в отличие от обычных слов где И совсем редуцируется(может быть редуцирована) и смягчает согласный: кошки - к о ш к' , но пришёл - т ы/а к' и а не пришёл- т ы/а к'. У меня не получается редуцировать И при произнесении, а буква А редуцируется как предударная. Как, например, в слове человеки - в котором тоже И нарочито выпячивается.

Comment: Я вам немного позже отвечу в поле ответов.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий**

1. Вы правы, хотя качественно мы определяем один и тот же звук И, но **фонетика у разных вариантов  различная** – по спектрометру это можно определить. При дефисном написании фонетическое слово имеет основное и вспомогательное ударение, а при раздельном – у каждого слова собственное ударение.

Но в предложении **общая картина меняется,** из отдельных слов образуются фонетические фразы  с общим фразовым ударение, которое падает на ударный слог одного из слов, и оно тогда будет выделено. На частицу фразовое ударение вряд ли будет падать, но **на слух мы все равно определим** ее раздельное или дефисное письмо внутри фразы.

2. И возникает мысль: почему мы выделяем **именно глаголы** с двумя написаниями частицы? А чем другие слова хуже? Пусть действует **одно правило для всех.** В препозицию (для остальных слов)  мы частицу ставим редко, но пусть будет одно правило в постпозиции «таки», например: *Всё-таки, он-таки, пришел-таки. Сложный-таки, язык-таки, всё-таки.* Забавно! Как вы думаете о такой «реформе» правила?:))

Любопытно также, как в классической литературе писалась частица «таки» в разной позиции относительно всех слов, когда ещё не было **общего свода правил.**

3. Но это уже тема для новых вопросов, а ответ по этой теме **я принимаю**. Хотя решение этой проблемы еще только намечено, но вы предложили, как мне думается, **конструктивное направление.** И спасибо вам за вашу активность на форуме и за нестандартное мышление, которое я особенно ценю.

**Дополнительный материал по теме**

**(1) Вопросы на форуме**
[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474102/Я-кот-таки-Я-кот-таки](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474102/%D0%AF-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%AF-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8)
[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474097/Всё-таки-то-или-всё-таки-то](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474097/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%91-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE)

**(2) О значении слова «таки»**
[https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/таки](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8)

**ТАКИ́, частица.** Разг.

Употребляется при местоимениях и наречиях, **подчеркивая их значение**. — Разве он пьет? — спросила Юлия. — Пьет, матушка, и порядочно-таки этим занимается. Писемский, Тюфяк.

При глаголе выступает в значении: ***тем не менее, всё же, всё-таки.*** Но хоть и велик был соблазн, я таки успел побороть себя. Достоевский, Униженные и оскорбленные. — Сережа, ты завтра принесешь-таки двойку. Сию минуту садись заниматься! Серафимович, Сережа.

В разных значениях можно увидеть **семантический** путь решения задачи.

**(3) Статья "Как пишется слово "ТАКИ" - с дефисом или без?"**

https://dzen.ru/a/WzNFCRwX4wCoKjQ-
Там есть  **интересные комментарии.**

(4) **Мне нравится** частица "таки", если она уместна, тогда она придает речи определенный колорит. Но есть мнение, что «таки» используют люди определенной национальности. Ну, не знаю… А это отрывок из детской книги Н. Абгарян «Манюня», где есть частица «таки»  **в разных позициях:**

Дети нашалили (шлимазлы этакие), и строгая баба Роза ругает их:

*— Только что всё вымыла, и вот на тебе, отвернулась на миг, а они уже устроили разгром! Вы люди или кто?  Я **таки** спрашиваю вас — вы люди или кто??*

*— **Таки** я вас ещё раз спрашиваю, вы люди или кто???*

*Мы взвизгнули жалобно.*

*— Баааа, ну что ты спрашиваешь, ты не видишь, что мы девочки? — проскулила Манюня.*

*— Де-воч-ки, — передразнила баба Роза…*

Answer (score 0):

Ну, в примерах с дефисом ‟таки” стоит после слова, к которому относится, а в примерах с раздельным написанием оно стоит перед словом, к которому относится.

> **‟Таки” перед:** Я таки запер её и в этот раз.
> **‟Таки” после:** Я запер-таки её и в этот раз.

> **‟Таки” перед:** Я таки запер её и в этот раз.
> **‟Таки” после:** Я запер-таки её и в этот раз.

И обратите внимание, кстати, что даже в такой простой ситуации Розенталь умудрился написать какой-то бред про части речи. Этого человека на выстрел нельзя было подпускать к написанию каких-либо пособий или статей.

Comment: Спасибо, но это уже применение правила, а меня интересует, как объяснить  само правило.

Comment: Интонацией это всё объясняется. Когда ‟таки” перед словом, к которому оно относится, то там приличная пауза в отличии от ситуации, когда ‟таки” следует после.

Comment: Интонацию не очень-то приветствуют и ставят ниже других принципов в пунктуации. К тому же произношение выражает определенную семантику  и грамматику, именно так должна объясняться причина.

Comment: Я ни слова не понял из того, что вы написали. Есть такой пунктуационный принцип, как интонационный. Это ничего не значит для конкретной ситуации, потому что при наличии паузы может существовать условность, что запятая не ставится, а при отсутствии паузы может существовать условность, что запятая ставится. В этой конкретной ситуации вот люди установили такое правило, что при ‟таки” после пауза крайне мала и что тут подходит дефис, а если ‟таки” перед, то пауза велика и тут ничего не надо ставить. Вот есть такое правило, при создании его была некая такая вот логика, а остальное меня вообще не

Comment: интересует......

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю вопросов "Как можно объяснить пунктуацию". Ну вот договорились так. Какие-то мелкие причины у них были, но меня это вообще не интересует. В английском вообще половина наших запятых не ставится и живут люди неплохо.

Comment: @ 
user190920
 Я не согласна, а в договоры не верю:)  Все у нас логично (а как у них, это их дело), просто глубинный смысл правил надо понять. Нам это не объясняют, а обычно только формулируют правила. Остальное – за кадром.